# MVC model binding in controller action when given a querystring with special character keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a third party library for a Grid which uses fixed querystring parameters as shown below.

```
/Home/GetData/?$skip=0&$top=10
```

These parameters have a `$` in their key and I wanted to know if there is a way to still have the MVC model binding work for these parameters.

i.e.

applying them to this action (which won't compile because of the $ in the parameter names.

```
public ActionResult GetData(int $skip, int $top)
{
...
return View();
}
```

Comment: You might need a custom model binder for that. That would be a good solution. Quick and dirty way though is to parse query string inside action

Comment: Oh, and quick search revealed following thing: [ActionParameterAlias Nuget package](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/adding-an-alias-to-an-action-parameter-for-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc/). Never saw it in action frankly, but might be worth a try.

Comment: @Andrei thanks that pointed me in the right direction, I have added what I just tried and both seem to work ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andrei for pointing me in the right direction.

The below solutions both do the trick.

Via prefix alias model binding

```
public ActionResult GetData([Bind(Prefix = "$top")]int top = 0, [Bind(Prefix = "$skip")]int skip = 0)
{
    return View();
}
```

By Request object to get the Querystring values

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var topParam = Request.QueryString["$top"];
    var skipParam = Request.QueryString["$skip"];

    var top = 0;
    int.TryParse(topParam, out top);

    var skip = 0;
    int.TryParse(skipParam, out skip);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Did not know about this `BindAttribute`, quite useful thing. Cool!